# Oracle Pro*C 12.1 - standard output content not redirected to file when generating core dump

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, oracle12c

I am facing a rather strange issue with Oracle Pro*C precompiler on linux: as part of our build process, we invoke the proc utility to generate .cxx files that later get compiled as C++ source files. This proc utility is called through a python script, which captures both stdout and stderr and prints them both in case of a non-0 return code. Whenever the precompiler encounters a compilation error, it reports them on standard output which gets correctly printed out and returns a non-0 return code.

However in our CI environment the precompiler systematically crashes returning a negative return code, with nothing getting printed out neither on standard output nor on standard error.

My ultimate goal is to understand this crash and fix it, but I am unable to reproduce that particular crash outside our CI environment. I managed however to generate a different crash of the proc utility on a linux VM by passing bogus include folders as arguments. And I witness a strange behaviour in my bash terminal, which explains while I get no output at all from my python script. When calling proc directly, the error message is correctly printed out in my terminal:

```
$> /path/to/proc option_1=foo option2=bar

Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Dec 4 08:13:31 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Error at line 3, column 10 in file /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h
#include <bits/wordsize.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 39, column 10 in file /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h
#include <features.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Syntax error at line 44, column 21, file /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h:
Error at line 44, column 21 in file /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
....................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

)

Syntax error at line -1741187720, column 0, file p�:

INTERNAL ERROR: Failed assertion [PGE Code=90105]

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$>
```

When redirecting the standard output to a file, no error message gets printed out except the last line regarding a core having been generated. However the file containing the redirected output is empty:

```
$> /path/to/proc option_1=foo option2=bar > test.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$> more test.txt
$> ls -al test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0  3 déc 20:27 test.txt
$>
```

Also the output of piping to `cat` results in nothing being printed out at all:

```
$> /path/to/proc option_1=foo option2=bar | cat
$>
```

Based on that I have 2 questions:

- how is it possible the output does not make it to a file when redirected ?
- how else could I attempt to capture it ?

Comment: What is output of `/path/to/proc option_1=foo option2=bar | cat`?

Comment: The output is empty, I added this result to the question above directly

Comment: Your program (/path/to/proc) checks whether the output is redirected. Check your program's documentation to see if there are options to redirect the output to a file.